# Можно ли продавать софт, написанный на основе AutoHotkey?

Tags: лицензирование, autohotkey

Вот, допустим, я написал скрипт под AutoHotkey, скомпилировал его в .exe. Могу ли я продавать этот экзешник, если AHK распространяется под лицензией GPL?

> Программа, созданная на основе «свободного» кода, должна распространяться также на условиях GPL, она не может быть переведена на коммерческую лицензию модификаторами и прочими «третьими лицами».

Так пишет [licenseit.ru](http://licenseit.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F:GNU_GPL_3_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC). Считается ли мой экзешник созданным «на основе» кода AHK?

Comment: Самый главный вопрос, кто её купит? :) остальное лирика..

Comment: Вопрос был не об этом :–)

Comment: нет не можете, зато вы можете продавать "техническую поддержку" к ней.

Answer (score 2):

Как таковое, распространение данной программы возможно, если вы не присваиваете данную программу себе. То есть, вы не говорите что не использовали какие либо сторонние программы для написания данного скрипта. А так почему нет? Всё возможно. Главное чтобы это не было вредоносное ПО.

Answer (score 2):

[Does the GPL allow me to sell copies of the program for money?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney)

> Yes, the GPL allows everyone to do this. The right to sell copies is
>   part of the definition of free software. Except in one special
>   situation, there is no limit on what price you can charge. (The one
>   exception is the required written offer to provide source code that
>   must accompany binary-only release.)

Даже на русском есть: [Продажа свободных программ](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html).

Так что да, можно. Просто вы должны по требованию предоставить сорсы своей программы.

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос, добавлю своё мнение. Продаёте вы не программу AutoHotkey, а свой скрипт. По моему мнению, скомпилированный скрипт не является программой созданный на основе AHK, а лишь с помощью её. Тогда бы запретили продавать все программы, к примеру написанные на c++, и скомпилированными компиляторами с GPL лицензией.

Вопрос в другом. Хотите продавать exe, но не хотите раскрывать исходник скрипта? Но на самом деле AHK скрипт не компилируется, и его относительно легко можно получить из ресурсов exe. Что бы более менее защитить скрипт надо внести изменения в программу AHK. И если не предоставить исходники вашей версии программы, то это нарушит лицензию. Наверное))

Comment: у вас ошибочное представление о свободных программах. смотрите: [о продаже свободных программ вообще](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.ru.html) и [о продаже копий программ под gpl в частности](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ru.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney), ну и в самом тексте лицензии: [For example, if you distribute copies of such a program, whether gratis or **for a fee**, you must pass on to the recipients the same freedoms that you received.](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.ru.html), (продолжение в следующем комментарии из-за ограничения объёма)

Comment: и в неофициальном переводе: [Например, если вы распространяете экземпляры такого программного обеспечения **за плату** или бесплатно, вы обязаны передать новым обладателям все права в том же объеме, в каком они принадлежат вам.](https://www.webcitation.org/6EzD4wQtG?url=http://jxself.org/translations/gpl-2.ru.shtml). резюме: вы можете продавать **и экземпляры** программы autohotkeys в том числе.

Comment: Эту статью я читал. В моём комментарии я не пытался спорить, что продавать свободный продукт нельзя. А хотел донести мысль, что автор  вовсе не продает AutoHotkey и даже не распространяет, а значит лицензия не распространяется на его скрипт.
Ну не исключено, что я в чем о ошибаюсь.

Comment: Проясню: моя идея была в том, чтоб продавать не сам код, а сервис по его написанию, который я оказываю. Те, кто не умеет писать код на АНК, но хотят пользоваться моим скриптом, покупают его и получают готовый код без необходимости разбираться в АНК и писать такой же. Чтобы избавить их от заморочек по поводу самого AHK, я компилирую его в .ехе. А тем, кто умеет писать код на АНК, а значит, и знает, что из .exe можно получить .ahk, я не вижу смысла продавать этот сервис по понятным причинам. Правильно ли я понимаю, что чтобы соблюсти условия лицензии, я должен вместе с экзешником отдавать .ahk?